# Open multiple javascript popup boxes with one button click

Tags: javascript

This is a JavaScript question.

I need to create a button which, when clicked once, will open up 5 sub-windows (popup boxes).

One box will be in the top left corner of the screen, one in the top right corner, one in the lower left corner, one in the lower right corner, and one in the center. Each box will have a different URL.

When the main window is closed, all of the sub-windows should also close.

I have only been able to do the code that opens one popup - cannot figure out how to code all 5 to open at once with one button click and then close them all when the parent window closes.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
function myPopup(URL) {
popupWindow = window.open(URL,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=500,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
}
</SCRIPT>

<a href="#" onclick="myPopup(this.href);return false">Open Pop-Up</a>
```

Many thanks to anyone who can help me out.

---

Thanks to everyone who is helping me. By utilizing the feedback here, I have worked on this project all day and have come up with some code that works. I was not sure how to assign urls for each popup to the array - but at least they work.

However, I can not get all the popups to close when the parent window closes. Hope you can help. Here is the new code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/*Use Array - Open 5 new popup windows using onclick*/

function newWindow() {
 var winPop = new Array();
  winPop[winPop.length] = window.open('top_right.html','window1','scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=1000,top=200,screenX=1000,screenY=200');
window.open('top_left.html','window2','scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=325,top=200,screenX=325,screenY=200');
window.open('bottom_left.html','window3','scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=325,top=600,screenX=325,screenY=600');
window.open('bottom_right.html','window4','scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=1000,top=600,screenX=1000,screenY=600');
window.open('center_page.html','window5','scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=660,top=450,screenX=660,screenY=450');
}

/*NOT WORKING FOR ME --Close all popups when parent window is closed*/

onbeforeunload = function() {
    for (var index = 0; index < winPop.length; ++index)
        winPop[index].close();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap"> <a href='' onclick='newWindow()'><img src='images/group_clicker.gif' border='0'></a> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hint: if calling `window.open()` _once_ opens _one_ window, what would calling `window.open()` _five times_ do? (Assuming the browser's popup-blocking settings don't put the kibosh on the whole thing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5MPWF/8/)**

Save all opened windows to an array.
Register for the [beforeUnload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload) event, and when it fires, loop through the popups `close()`'ing them.

NB: I think it's jsFiddle or Chrome, but it won't open more than 1 popup per click.

And due to restrictions placed on popup opening you cannot reliably control the position of opened popups. It may be useful for you to open in-window popups like [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/2/)'s [panel](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/panel-resize_source.html) or [jQuery(UI)](http://jqueryui.com/)'s [dialogue](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

```js
function openPopup(howMany) {
    var popups = [];

    var temp;
    for (var index = 0; index < howMany; ++index) {
        popups.push(open('', '', 'height=500,width=500'));
        popups[index].document.write('popup ' + (index + 1) + ' of ' + howMany + '<br/>this will close on parent window close');
    }

    closeFunc = function() {
        for (var index = 0; index < popups.length; ++index)
            popups[index].close();
    };

    if (addEventListener)
        addEventListener('beforeunload', closeFunc, false);
    else
        attachEvent('onbeforeunload', closeFunc);
}
```

Comment: Hello and a big thank you! I am trying to apply this array to my project but having problems closing all popups on parent window close. Mu current code is posted in original question.

Comment: your not actually adding any of them to the array. Use array.push()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: don't forget, if an answer helps you, let others know by upvoting it (hitting the up arrow next to it) even if it doesn't answer you question (which is what the tick is for).<br/>
Also, see my other answer to fix what you've changed in your question. Should work then

Comment: Just to let you know, I figured out where to place my code into your demo code. The script works great now! I wasn't able to upvote your answer because when I tried, a notice appeared that said 15 reputation points are required to do that. I only have 1 point. But I did select your demo as the answer I used. Thank you Hashbrown!

Comment: no worries, remember to contribute answers if you come across a question you know the answer to!

Comment: also, remember to understand the code, not just find out where it fits. Why did I use `if (addEventListener)`, what does `.push()` do? Google around and use fantastic resources like http://help.dottoro.com/ to *learn*, not simply *solve*

Comment: @Hashbrown Not working on Chrome.. is there any hack to make is work on chrome ??

Comment: it's working fine (just tested it), make sure that there isn't anything in the upper right corner saying `popup blocked`. Also StackOverflow 101; *what* isn't working? What *did* happen when you tried the snippet?

Comment: This is only working on firefox, all other browsers block all but the first pop up. Do you know if there is any hack for this?

Comment: nah, unfortunately as soon as there is a fix, or deliberate lack of feature, done in the name of security (like blocking multiple popups, inability to invoke context menu, et cetera) there is no work around. It wouldn't be very secure otherwise.

Comment: Having said that, I guess just have a google, you may find someone who has managed to do it by delaying the popups opening by a second or so (maybe the browsers don't think multiple popups are an issue if opened far enough apart *shrugs*)

Comment: nope, looks like [Chrome's too clever for that](https://jsfiddle.net/5MPWF/133/). But yeah, there may be a solution *somewhere*

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop to open multiple windows. Be sure to give a unique name to popup window

```
function myPopup(URL) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var popupWindow = window.open(URL, i, 'height=500,width=500,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your edit:

You wrote

```js
function newWindow() {
 var winPop = new Array();
  winPop[winPop.length] = window.open('top_right.html','window1','scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=1000,top=200,screenX=1000,screenY=200');
window.open('top_left.html','window2','scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=325,top=200,screenX=325,screenY=200');
window.open('bottom_left.html','window3','scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=325,top=600,screenX=325,screenY=600');
window.open('bottom_right.html','window4','scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=1000,top=600,screenX=1000,screenY=600');
window.open('center_page.html','window5','scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=660,top=450,screenX=660,screenY=450');
}
```

What you need is

```
var winPop;

function newWindow() {
    winPop = [
        open(
            'top_right.html',
            'window1',
            'scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=1000,top=200,screenX=1000,screenY=200'
        ),
        open(
            'top_left.html',
            'window2',
            'scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=325,top=200,screenX=325,screenY=200'
        ),
        open(
            'bottom_left.html',
            'window3',
            'scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=325,top=600,screenX=325,screenY=600'
        ),
        open(
            'bottom_right.html',
            'window4',
            'scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=1000,top=600,screenX=1000,screenY=600'
        ),
        open(
            'center_page.html',
            'window5',
            'scrollbars=no,width=235,height=155,left=660,top=450,screenX=660,screenY=450'
        )
    ];
}
```

This is a scoping issue (as well as you not actually adding the windows to the array :|), winPop needs to be `global`, I.e. `var`d outside of the function.

Comment: Hi Hashbrown, thanks for sticking with me on this. I see what you mean about using a global variable and I have now used the corrected code in my script. Your Demo works perfectly, but sadly, I have tried all morning to combine my URLs and accompanying attributes with the demo code and have pretty much made a mess of it. It seems that I should insert the URLs etc. after: popups.push(open('', but that is not working. Can you show me where I would place this code? Also I appreciate the tip about upvoting. I'm new here and didn't know about that.